# How set a breakpoint when ListBox size change

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listbox

I have a ListBox inside a GroupBox to show a log, but sometimes the listbox size change and go beyond the group box.

[image]

The function is using a `BackgroundWorker` and a `Timer`

`Timer_tick` is

```
if (!bgProcess.IsBusy)
{
    bgProcess.RunWorkerAsync();
}
else
{
    lstLog.Items.Insert(0, DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Busy");
}
```

The `BackgroundWorker` function end like this

```
if (lstLog.Items.Count > 800)
{
     lstLog.Items.Clear();
}
lstLog.Items.Insert(0, strItem);
```

I know probably hard to anyone know why this is happening. And right now not sure when the size change. I only know when I came back after a while and find it bigger.

So I will ask for how can I set a breakpoint for when the ListBox size change so I can try to find where/when is that happenning.

Answer (score 0):

Right clic on the line where you want to stop and then press Condition.

[image: Select this option]

then you have to create a condition to stop execution, something like this:
[image: Condition to Stop]

Pay attention to select "**Has changed**" option.

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: That is the problem. I dont know where the error occurs.

Comment: How about the SizeChanged event? And then have a look at the call stack?